# Using Drop Down For Nav in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that uses Bootstrap 3. I need to create a page that uses a drop down for navigation. I want it to behave like tabs though. In other words, when a user chooses an item in the drop down, I want the content to change underneath the tabs. I want the title (Order Info) and the drop down to always be visible and the content below those to change. In other words:

```
Order Info         +-----------------+
                   | [icon] View 1 v |
                   +-----------------+
                   |     [icon] V2   |
                   |     [icon] V3   |
                   |     [icon] V4   | 
                   +-----------------+
[Content here changes]
```

When the content changes, the selected tab name should be the one selected in the drop down. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>Order Info</h2>
        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="viewDropDown" aria-expanded="true">
                View Name
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">View 2</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">View 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    [Tab Content Goes Here]
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you use jQuery/javascript on this project? Are you trying to load content via AJAX, or just hide/show content already loaded on the page?

Comment: Can you past you entire Jquery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here if you see I have hidden the actual tab links `#myTab` and use the dropdown to trigger the tab links using JS. I have set a `data-target` to each link in the dropdown eg: `data-target="#home"` and use this data attribute to trigger the tab links. Hope this is what you wanted.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Order Info</h2>    
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a id="drop5" href="#" class="btn btn-default  dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                  My Account
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul id="menu2" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop5">
                   <li role="presentation" class="active"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-target="#home">Home</a></li>
                   <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-target="#profile">Profile</a></li>
                   <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-target="#messages">Messages</a></li>
                   <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-target="#settings">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>

        </div><hr />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div role="tabpanel">
                <!-- hide the below links-->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display:none;" role="tablist" id="myTab">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
                        <h4>Home</h4>...
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile"> 
                        <h4>Profile</h4>...
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="messages"> 
                        <h4>Messages</h4...
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="settings"> 
                        <h4>Settings</h4>...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS: Here we bind a click event to the anchor links of the dropdown and trigger the tab.

```
$('#menu2 li a').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);             
    var parent = $this.closest('li');
    var target = $this.data('target');          // #home, #profile, #messages, #settings

    var btn = $this.closest('.dropdown').find('.btn.dropdown-toggle');  // the button element 
    var str = $this.text() + " <span class='caret'></span>";  // get text of the element clicked

    parent.siblings().removeClass('active');      // removing active class if present 
    parent.addClass('active');                    // adding class active to current element

    btn.html(str);                                // setting button text
    $('#myTab a[href="'+target+'"]').tab('show'); // on basis of data-target trigger the tab link
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/4xx4gsz9/5/)

Comment: There is one critical piece that I couldn't figure out. When a user chooses an option (for instance "Messages" in your fiddle), the text in the drop down does not change. In your fiddle I was expecting "My Account" to be replaced with "Messages". How do you do that?

Comment: Have updated the answer. Since this dropdown is not really a select box you have to set the text manually in your script on click of the anchor element.